# EC2 Connection Timed out: ec2 ERROR: asyncio completed with error: 10061,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have ec2 instance with public subnet and vpc associate with it.and igw attach to the vpc

I did enable auto assign ip

Also I have security group with following inbound rules

[image]

the route table look like

[image]

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-XX-XXX.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ec2-XX-XXX.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com [XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ec2-XX-XXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-XX-XXX.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the following things

- you have mentioned that you have attached the IG to the vpc, verify that you have made the route table changes of routing default traffic to IG so that your instance is reachable through IG.
- check for iptable rules which might deny ssh

Comment: routing looks fine, IPTable rules also verified?

Comment: without connect how would i check it?

Comment: I generally install aws ssm manager using init script, which allows me to run commands without logging in, ignore it, its not possible without it.